# Help with two probability questions. Classic definition of probability.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The first can be done using condition probability, but was wondering how to do it just with the classic definition of probability? Both questions are in the same part of the book, and therefore i would assume the same technique would be used to solve them.
B- black ball C- cream ball

$1.)$ In the first box there are 3B and 7C, in the second 4B and 6 C, in the third  8B and 2C balls. From the first box a ball is drawn put in second, then from the second a ball is drawn , put in third and lastly , from the last box a ball is drawn and put into the first. Find the probabilities for each box the the composition will stay the same. Answer: $p_1={241\over 605};  p_2={32\over 55} ;p_3= {27\over 55}$ How is this?

$2.)$ In a game 10 boys participated. They lost 5 marbles, then found them. What is the probability that 3 (exactly )boys found the marbles. Answer: $${10 \times9\times 8[2 \binom 53+ 3\binom 52]\over 10^5}  $$

Comment: I assume the second problem is of greater interest than the first (since in order to solve the first, even by conditional probabilities, you must have some insight into the structure of successful outcomes).  But the second part seems to have little indication of what the probability space is.  Does the chances of a boy finding a marble relate to the event of that boy having lost a marble?  Does each boy have an equal chance of finding each marble?

Comment: Yes, each boy has an equal chance. Losing and finding a marble in terms of this problem are not related

Comment: Thats what i thought as well! So i posted it here. Little indication of prob space

Comment: If you assume that is the probability space (consistent with the denominator $10^5$ counting the number of ways five marbles could be assigned to ten boys), can you work the problem?  We are here to help if you have a specific difficulty.

Comment: The numerator is completely foreign i cannot make out logicly how that counts for favourable outcomes

Comment: In the first question, i also am having difficulty solving without conditional prob..

Comment: I would just work the problem in your own terms.  Something like the numerator must emerge to account for the way five marbles get distributed among exactly three boys (each must have at least one, so...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If $B_i,C_i$ denote, respectively, black and cream balls drawn from the $i^{th}$ box, then the three required probabilities are

\begin{eqnarray*}
p_1 &=& P(B_1B_2B_3) + P(B_1C_2B_3) + P(C_1C_2C_3) + P(C_1B_2C_3) \\
&=& \dfrac{3}{10}\cdot\dfrac{5}{11}\cdot\dfrac{9}{11} + \dfrac{3}{10}\cdot\dfrac{6}{11}\cdot\dfrac{8}{11} + \dfrac{7}{10}\cdot\dfrac{7}{11}\cdot\dfrac{3}{11} + \dfrac{7}{10}\cdot\dfrac{4}{11}\cdot\dfrac{2}{11} \\ 
&& \\
&=& \dfrac{241}{605} \\
&& \\
p_2 &=& P(B_1B_2) + P(C_1C_2) \\
&=& \dfrac{3}{10}\cdot\dfrac{5}{11} + \dfrac{7}{10}\cdot\dfrac{7}{11} \\ 
&& \\
&=& \dfrac{32}{55} \\
&& \\
p_3 &=& P(B_1B_2B_3) + P(C_1B_2B_3) + P(C_1C_2C_3) + P(B_1C_2C_3) \\
&=& \dfrac{3}{10}\cdot\dfrac{5}{11}\cdot\dfrac{9}{11} + \dfrac{7}{10}\cdot\dfrac{4}{11}\cdot\dfrac{9}{11} + \dfrac{7}{10}\cdot\dfrac{7}{11}\cdot\dfrac{3}{11} + \dfrac{3}{10}\cdot\dfrac{6}{11}\cdot\dfrac{3}{11} \\ 
&& \\
&=& \dfrac{27}{55}.
\end{eqnarray*}

$\\$

2. Number the balls so they are distinguishable. Firstly, the total number of ways to arrange $5$ marbles among $10$ boys is $10^5$. This becomes the denominator.

The numerator is meant to be the number of ways to arrange the $5$ marbles among exactly $3$ of the $10$ boys - but I think the value given is wrong. I'll explain what I think they've done and then what I think is a correction.

The number of ways to choose $3$ boys (where order is important) is $10\cdot 9\cdot 8$. For each such selection we can either allocate $3$ marbles to Boy $1$ and one each to Boys $2$ and $3$ - there are $\binom{5}{3}\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1}$ ways to do this - or allocate $2$ marbles each to Boys $1$ and $2$ and $1$ marble to Boy $3$ - there are $\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}\binom{1}{1}$ ways to do this. Putting this together we get:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\text{#ways to allocate $5$ marbles to exactly $3$ boys} &=& 10\cdot 9\cdot 8 \left[2\binom{5}{3} + 3\binom{5}{2}\right].
\end{eqnarray*}

The problem I see is that there is double-counting in the two scenarios. In the $3-1-1$ scenario, $\binom{5}{3}\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1}$ counts these two allocations of marbles separately:

$$\text{Boy } 1: 1,2,3\qquad\qquad \text{Boy } 2: 4\qquad\qquad \text{Boy } 3: 5 \\
\text{Boy } 1: 1,2,3\qquad\qquad \text{Boy } 2: 5\qquad\qquad \text{Boy } 3: 4.$$

But it shouldn't because these are counted by *two* ordered arrangements of $3$ boys: $1,2,3$ and $1,3,2$.

So we should divide by $2$ the count for that scenario. A similar problem occurs for the $2-2-1$ scenario (because two boys again have an equal number of marbles) so we should also divide this count by $2$.

So the correct answer is, I think:

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(\text{$3$ boys find $5$ marbles}) &=& \dfrac{\text{#ways to allocate $5$ marbles to exactly $3$ boys}}{\text{#ways to allocate $5$ marbles to $10$ boys}} \\
&& \\
&=& \dfrac{10\cdot 9\cdot 8 \left[\binom{5}{3} + \frac{3}{2}\binom{5}{2}\right]}{10^5}.
\end{eqnarray*}